# Vector bundles' conjectures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Hi,

I know the title sounds too much general. 
Googling the question I have not found much material, so I decided to ask to experts.
I would like to know which are the most famous/important unsolved conjectures for vector bundles on algebraic curves, which are the known consequences and why they seem evident.

Thank you

Comment: I had initially read your title as «Victor Bundles' conjectures» and I marveled at the guy ending up working on vector bundles...

Comment: Hi unkn21: I think that this question is too open-ended for this forum, and so I've voted to close.  I do recommend that you ask specific questions about your research re:vector bundles on algebraic curves.  Also, please look over http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask  and read some of the successful MO questions for a sense of what types of questions work best here.  In the meantime, it looks like you do have a correct answer below, from an unknown (google) account.

Answer (score 2):

There's an article  "A problem list on vector bundles" written by Eduardo Ballico.You can find it in the book"Complex analysis and geometry" Edited by Vincenzo Ancona and Alessandro Silva,Plenum Press.I happen to know this article when reading another topic in this book.Maybe it is useful.